# A SQL using Sum and Group By for multiple tables with different primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Let’s say I have following tables: inv_mast, po_hdr, po_line and vessel_receipts_line
And I have following data:

```
inv_mast.inv_mast_uid
12
2852

po_hdr.po_no
1000019
1000118

po_line.po_no|line_id|po_line_uid|inv_mast_uid
1000019      |1      |234        |12
1000118      |1      |646        |2852
1000118      |2      |648        |2852

vessel_receipts_line.po_line_uid|container_qty_received|row_status_flag
234                             |9700                  |702
646                             |320000                |702
646                             |2710000               |701
648                             |3250000               |702
```

Now I’m trying to sum the container_qty_received for each po_no + inv_mast_uid + row_status_flag, which should be 702. 
For example, the result I expected is

```
po_no  |inv_mast_uid|container_qty_received|row_status_flag
1000019|12          |9700                  |702
1000118|2852        |3570000               |702
1000118|2852        |2710000               |701
```

I have tried several different codes, with left join, or with subquery, none of them work. The two quantities just don't sum. 
The result now is:

```
po_no  |inv_mast_uid|container_qty_received
1000019|12          |9700
1000118|2852        |320000
1000118|2852        |3250000
```

Here is one of my attempts.

```
SELECT a.inv_mast_uid
, b.qty_in_vessel as qty_in_vessel
, c.po_no
FROM po_line a
LEFT JOIN
po_hdr AS c ON a.po_no = c.po_no
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT vessel_receipts_line.po_line_uid, SUM(vessel_receipts_line.container_qty_received) AS qty_in_vessel
FROM vessel_receipts_line
WHERE vessel_receipts_line.row_status_flag = 702
GROUP BY
vessel_receipts_line.po_line_uid
) AS b
ON b.po_line_uid = a.po_line_uid
GROUP BY
a.inv_mast_uid, b.qty_in_vessel, c.po_no
ORDER BY c.po_no
```

Please help!

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `po_line` and `vessel_receipts_line` on `po_line_uid`, group by `po_no` and `inv_mast_uid` and sum the `container_qty_received`.

```
SELECT pl.po_no,
       pl.inv_mast_uid,
       vrl.row_status_flag,
       sum(vrl.container_qty_received) container_qty_received
       FROM po_line pl
            INNER JOIN vessel_receipts_line vrl
                       ON vrl.po_line_uid = pl.po_line_uid
       GROUP BY pl.po_no,
                pl.inv_mast_uid,
                vrl.row_status_flag;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f03c66465892c30838c2ad5ce575f393)

Comment: The result is still wrong. It shows 6280000 for po_no 1000118 and inv_mast_uid 2852. I think some of them have been summed twice.

Comment: @Leon: It does work in terms of producing your desired result with the given sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6c8cea13dc8153599f964c9feaa8afc8

Comment: Trust me, your solution is the same as my first attempt. It will double the quantity. That's why I use subquery here. Thanks though, you are really prompt.

Comment: @Leon: Have you looked at the fiddle? It doesn't double anything. It returns 3570000 for 1000118 / 2852, which is what you wrote you'd expect.

Comment: OK. Let me check the data. Maybe I missed something. Sorry, it's not what I want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question. Added one more column which is row_status_flag. That's why we got the different result.

Comment: @Leon: Doesn't really fundamentally change the query. There's just one column more. See the edit.